# Is there a way to dynamically pass multiple keys for partition in Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Right now, multiple keys can be given one after the other and each key can be given dynamically but is there a way to pass entire "Unique Value Per Partition" field by passing a list of keys or something.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Pseudo code maybe...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fixed range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#fixed-range) partitioning and build an expression that provides a fixed range of values.

[image]